# C# MVC Jquery Ajax - syntaxerror unexpected token in json at position 0

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to update record status using ajax method,
But stuck at this error : **syntaxerror unexpected token in json at position 0**

Controller code :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(string uniqueId, string statusId)
{
  try
  {
    HM.Services.EnquiryService enquiryService = new Services.EnquiryService(unitOfWork, new SQLRepository<Enquiries>(unitOfWork));
    var userModel = enquiryService.UpdateStatus(new Guid(uniqueId), Convert.ToInt32(statusId));
    if (userModel != null)
    {
      return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "success", title = "Success", msg = "Enquiry status changed successfully." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
     return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "error", title = "Failed", msg = "Enquiry status change failed!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "error", title = "Error occurred", msg = exc.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Jquery code :

```
var PostData = {};
PostData.uniqueId = enquiryGuid;
PostData.statusId = statusId;
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
url: '@(AppStaticClass.GetBaseUrl() + "Enquiry/UpdateStatus")',
data: PostData,
success: function (ReturnData) {
debugger
if (ReturnData.type == 'success') {
   grid.reload();
}
ShowMessage(ReturnData.type, ReturnData.title, ReturnData.msg);
},
complete: function (msg) {
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
ShowMessage('error', 'Error', thrownError);
}
});
```

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: What invalid token reported by console? Try removing `dataType: 'json'` on AJAX call if you feel the error caused by non-parseable string.

Comment: Remove dataType:'json' ,  now i can see response but it is in html format instead json.

Comment: Success method response is in html format, so not able to get expected json values. e.g. : success,msg,..

Comment: Well, your `ReturnData` has HTML format, but `dataType:json` expects JSON string to parse, so check Network tab in your browser to see HTTP response (maybe permission-related issue) & see if `ReturnMsgDefault` returns proper content.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : Yeah, issue was with Permission custom-action-filter attribute, which was redirecting to custom error page in response but due to ajax method i was not able to see response as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test project to try to reproduce your error. I could not.
Here is the code I used

```
public class AssetsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateStatus(string uniqueId, string statusId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (true)
            {
                return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "success", title = "Success", msg = "Enquiry status changed successfully." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "error", title = "Failed", msg = "Enquiry status change failed!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return Json(new ReturnMsgDefault { type = "error", title = "Error occurred", msg = exc.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
public class ReturnMsgDefault
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

and my view

```
<body>
    <div>
        <script>
            var PostData = {};
            PostData.uniqueId = "dwfsdf";
            PostData.statusId = "sdfsdfsdf";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateStatus")',
                data: PostData,
                success: function (returnData) {
                    console.log(returnData.title);
                },
                complete: function (msg) {
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    ShowMessage('error', 'Error', thrownError);
                }
            });
            function ShowMessage()
            {

            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

And I do not get any error.
[image: The result seems perfectly okay]
Do you know which path the controller takes ? If it is the error path, check the content of `exc.Message` to make sure it does not contain characters that will break the JSON.

If you try the slightly modified code that I provided, does it work ?

Comment: @Widrr : thanks for your time, Issue was with Permission custom-action-filter attribute, which was redirecting to custom error page in response but due to ajax method i was not able to see response as well.